# Test case for a service method which contains a HTTP subscribe - Angular HTTP RxJs

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test, httptestingcontroller

I'm having a service method and it has a service call (HTTP call) and it subscribes immediately and based on the response code it executes the rest of the action command.

Example: Service Method

```
processData(id): void {
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/data/${id}`;

    this.http.head(url).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Success');

        // Rest of the code - TODO

    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Failed');        

        // Rest of the code - TODO

    });
}
```

I tried the following sample (Test case)

```
fdescribe('ReportedFileService', () => {

    let service: DataService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports:[HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers:[DataService]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(DataService);
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        httpMock.verify();
    });

    fit('should be valid', () => {
        const id = 1;
        const filePath = `http://localhost:5000/data/${id}`;

        const req = httpMock.expectOne(filePath);

        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('Head');

        const response = service.processData(id);
    })
}
```

kindly assist me how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your service shouldn't be subscribing to the HttpClient observable and thus, it shouldn't be a void return type method. Services should be returning a HttpClient observable to be subscribed to.

E.g.

***Service Method***

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) //ensure service is provided at root level so it remains a singleton in the dependency injection tree.
...
constructor(http: HttpClient){}
...
processData(id): Observable<any> { //services should return an Observable
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/data/${id}`;
    return this.http.head(url); // ** your service method SHOULDN'T be subscribing to the HTTP call.
}
```

**Your service method shouldn't be subscribing to the HTTP call.
Invoking .subscribe() will cause the HTTP request to be made.**

Component using this service will first inject the service in the constructor. Then, **you will subscribe to the service call in the component.**

***SomeComponent.ts***

```
...
constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
...
someMethod(){
   this.processData().subscribe(
       (response) => { //subs
           console.log("success");
           // Rest of the code - TODO
       },
       (error) => {
           console.log('Failed');        

          // Rest of the code - TODO
       }
   )
}
```

Your test case should then subscribe to the service just like a component.

***service.spec.ts - your service test case***

```
fit('should be valid', fakeAsync(() => {
   const id = 1;

   service.subscribe( //you are making the http call in the test case.
       (success: any) => {
          expect(success.request.headers.get('Content-Type').toEqual('application/json')); //assert that the http headers you will get back from the observable is similar to the one the mock backend will return.
       }
   )

   httpMock.expectOne({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/data/${id}',
      method: 'HEAD'
   }).flush({}, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }); //HEAD requests have empty response body but only headers

});
```

Also, you shouldn't be calling localhost, when you have to deploy this app into a web server, you'd then have to manually change each string.

Instead you should be setting your API urls in the environments file, which is located in:

- `src/environments/environment.prod.ts` - contains actual domain. E.g. https://example.com/api/data/
- `src/environments/environment.ts` - contains localhost, local development server E.g. http://localhost:5000/data/${id}

You'd then import the environment urls as strings in such a manner:

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
...
const API_URL = environment.apiURL;
```

Here are some guides which had helped me and I had bookmarked:
Using angular's HttpClient module to send HTTP requests:
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-httpclient/

Testing services:
https://www.ng-conf.org/2019/angulars-httpclient-testing-depth/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information, It will take time to be online to check the code. I given a up-vote and once I get the result I'll approve it as answer.

Comment: Hi, Once I triggered the `flush` method, the chrome browser gets disconnect. Kindly assist me in `HEAD` request

Comment: My bad, I forgot it is a HEAD request. I have edited my answer for the "mock backend" to return headers and an empty http body as a HEAD request should do. The subscription should test if the headers returned are as expected. For the specifications, have a look at https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/TestRequest#flush

Comment: Still I'm facing issues. I posted the details in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57001238/angular-jasmine-test-case-gets-failed-in-http-head-request-while-on-flush

Comment: I have read your new question, your service method is still incorrect though. Perhaps I didn't explain well enough, I have further edited my answer.

Comment: The test case executed successfully `Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.037 secs)` but chrome get crashed `12 07 2019 12:47:15.886:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed - [14424:21784:0712/124715.833:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(221)] Waited 275 ms for network service`